# What is the async.retryable pattern for async.waterfall?

Tags: javascript, node.js, async.js

The [async documentation](https://github.com/caolan/async#retryableopts--times-5-interval-0-5-task) shows a `retryable` example for `async.auto` but I am wondering what the pattern looks like for `async.waterfall`? I have been unable to track down any examples. Would it look something like this:

```
async.waterfall([ 
    step1, 
    step2, 
    async.retryable([opts = {times: 5, interval: 3000}], step3), 
    step4 
    ], 
    function(error, result) { 
        if (error) { console.error(error); return; 
        } console.log(result); 
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

In doing further research I have confirmed this is the correct pattern for `async.retryable` in the context of `async.waterfall` below (step 3):

```
async.waterfall([ 
    step1, 
    step2, 
    async.retryable([opts = {times: 5, interval: 3000}], step3), 
    step4 
    ], 
    function(error, result) { 
        if (error) { console.error(error); return; 
        } console.log(result); 
    });
```